# Install oracle-java8 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java-8

Hace poco instale el JDK de Oracle de la siguiente manera:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

El problema es que ahora ya no se puede instalar, ya que al ejecutar el tercer comando, la terminal arroja un error

```
El paquete «oracle-java8-installer» no tiene un candidato para la instalación
```

Alguna manera de instalarlo ?

Comment: Revisa el siguiente link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Ten cuidado usando el JDK de Oracle. Para builds superiores a 202, la licencia cambió y requiere licencia comercial para usarlo en producción (y pues, si desarrollas en ese, supongo que despliegas con ese). Es posible que esa sea la causa de que no esté disponible en el repositorio

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que que ese paquete ya no esta disponible.

Como consejo, para instalar java te recomiendo utilizar sdkman.

https://sdkman.io/install

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Si quieres la ultima versión de java

```
sdk install java
```

Una versión en especial

```
sdk list java
```

Usas la columna que dice identificador, por ejemplo:

```
sdk install java 13.0.2-zulu
```

Al final te pregunta si quieres esa version por default

Te dejo el link al asciinema

https://asciinema.org/a/YBWAhf2dFVsPiAcIfgj6OhjXa